# Tesseract user-pattern is not applied

Tags: ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I want to do OCR on this image.[image]
This is pre-define format. ie first five will characters, then next four will be digits and last will be character.

When I execute following command

```
$ tesseract in.png stdout
```

I get output as **BDVPD474SQ**

So, I went for user-pattern.
I created a file(in directory */usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/configs*) named as **bazaar** (its content is as follow)

```
load_system_dawg     F
load_freq_dawg       F
user_patterns_suffix user-patterns
```

I also created a file, named as **eng.user-patterns** in directory */usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata* (its content is as follow)

```
\A\A\A\A\A\d\d\d\d\A
```

Still, I am getting same result

```
$ tesseract in.png stdout bazaar
BDVPD474SQ
```

What I am doing wrong ?
Has anyone accomplished this by Tess4j ?

Comment: I had to delete my post, since it was obviously wrong. I looked at the source ( https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/browse/dict/trie.h ), which proves your pattern correct. Also I tried your example and got the same result.

Comment: @JoOko So can we say that, this feature is not implemented ?

Comment: And still seems to be the case all these years later? :\

Comment: still facing same issue, there isn't much on how to use it

Answer (score 0):

You can add the option `--oem 0` to ensure user patterns apply. See this [PR comment](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/960#issuecomment-412773829).

Since I am on tesseract `5.3.3`, I had to tweak your input image to reproduce a similar behavior:

[image]

I specify the user pattern `\A\A\A\A\A\d\d\d\A\A`, to force recognition of the partially erased `9` character as a letter.

With `--oem 0`, Tesseract returns `BDVPD474SQ` (it reads an `S`).

Without the option, Tesseract returns `BDVPD474SQ` (identifying a `5`).