# Tweak tesseract for better detection of URLs in image

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I have an image that I can't get tesseract to recognise as text.  All my input text will be URLs.
[image]

As you can see, the image is as clear as it can be.

When running `tesseract test2.png stdout` it returns  `http:II11111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111.coml`
 Which is close, but not correct.

When setting the `tessedit_char_whitelist` parameter to `htp:/1.com` it recognises the string correctly (but I want more general recognition of URLs as well).

Passing in a pattern file that looks like below using command line `tesseract test2.png stdout --user-patterns ./patterns.txt`

```
\n\*://\n\*
http://\n\*
\n\*.com
```

doesn't help with recognition.  It still prefers `I` over `/`.  (More details about the [pattern file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209919/tesseract-user-patterns) )

I have also tried to set the parameters `ok_repeated_ch_non_alphanum_wds` to include `/` (and `chs_trailing_punct{1,2}` for trailing /, but it doesn't seem to work.  Specifying `--user-words` doesn't help either. (With "words" being `http://`)

Is there a way of specifying char priority for tesseract?

Version info:

```
$ tesseract -v
tesseract 3.04.01
 leptonica-1.73
  libgif 5.1.2 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.4.2) : libpng 1.2.54 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.2.8 : libwebp 0.4.4 : libopenjp2 2.1.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding the following line to your [unicharambigs](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract#the-unicharambigs-file)
file:

`3  : I I   3   : / /   1`

1. Extract the unicharambigs file with `combine_tessdata -e eng.traineddata eng.unicharambigs`
2. Edit the unicharambigs file, e.g. with `nano eng.unicharambigs` (make sure to use tabs after both 3s and the second /).
3. Overwrite the unicharambigs file in the traineddata file with the edited version `combine_tessdata -o eng.traineddata eng.unicharambigs`

Output using the amended traineddata file:

```
$ tesseract test2.png stdout
http://11111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111.coml
```

Comment: I added  the line `4       c o m l 4       c o m / 1` for last `/` `l` confusion, but your idea worked.